# Change Directory to symlink errors on Windows 10

Tags: windows, mklink

I created a 'symlink' on Windows 10 to a network share using the following cmmand it worked fine

```
mklink /D Lab_Handler "\\MYIP\UAT\Handlers"
symbolic link created for Lab_Handler <<===>> \\MYIP\\UAT\\Handlers
```

When I try to 'cd' to 'Lab_Handler' it errors as follows

```
D:\temp>cd Lab_Handler
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

However, I am able to open the 'symlink' from Windows explorer

What am I doing wrong (or) Where should I provide user name and password ?

**EDIT:**  The network share is password protected.   On Windows explorer when I access the Share it prompts for user name and password and when typed correctly it allows me to browse the Network share

Answer (score 4):

Prior to "cd Lab_Handler" from Command Prompt, I had to connect to the mapped network drive from command line that is

```
net use \\MYIP\UAT\Handlers
```

After executing the command mentioned above, it would prompt us to enter the username and password to establish the connectivity

And then, I was able to "cd Lab_handler" like any other normal directory